# Pathos "Error has occured during the function import"

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

When I try to execute this code:

```
import pathos
from network import *


def simulation(error_rate=1):
    network = Network(error_rate=1)
    network.gen_transceiver_pair(1)
    network.run()
    mend = network.master_transceivers[0].cycle[0, 2]
    send = network.slave_transceivers[0].cycle[0, 2]
    return send if send > mend else mend

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = pathos.pools.ParallelPool(nodes=10)
    result = p.map(simulation, [1, 1, 1])
```

I'm getting this error:

```
An error has occured during the function import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\network_simu\venv\lib\site-packages\ppft\__main__.py", line 100, in run
    six.exec_(__fobj)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in Network
NameError: name 'signal' is not defined
A fatal error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\network_simu\venv\lib\site-packages\ppft\__main__.py", line 109, in run
    __f = locals()[ppc.str_(__fname)]
KeyError: 'simulation'
```

Is it because I am generating a `Network` object inside of the function? Ideally I'd like to run the simulation 10^6-10^7 times with different error rate (1, .9, etc.). I tried to run with `multiprocessing` but couldn't pickle the function hence why I am trying with `Pathos`.

Edit: I am using `signal` from the `blinker` module. The code works when executed normally. I've done 10^6 iterations without any problem but it takes forever.

Edit2:
I am using the signal as such:

```
class Pool:
    def __init__(self):
        Transceiver.pool_add.connect(self.add)
        Transceiver.pool_remove.connect(self.remove)
        Network.return_cycle.connect(self.set_cycle)
        self.cycle = 0
        self.pool = []

    def set_cycle(self, sender):
        self.cycle = sender.cycle

    def add(self, sender):
        if VERBATIM:
            print("added " + sender.t_id)
        self.pool.insert(0, sender)
        sender.cycle[0, 0] = self.cycle

    def remove(self, sender):
        if VERBATIM:
            print("removed " + sender.t_id)
        self.pool.remove(sender)
        sender.cycle[0, 2] = self.cycle

class Transceiver(NetworkComponent):
    __STATUS = ["off", "t_on", "r_on", "on"]
    pool_add = signal("pool_add")
    pool_remove = signal("pool_remove")
    __ID = iter(range(1, 41))
```

Edit3: So I removed the use of `signal`. Now I get this error:

```
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
An error has occured during the function import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\network_simu\venv\lib\site-packages\ppft\__main__.py", line 100, in run
    six.exec_(__fobj)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in Network
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
A fatal error has occured during the function execution
```

`np` is `numpy`... weird

Comment: blinker is not guarantees the availability of the key "signal". You can process this exception without crash?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So normally since the processes do not share the same memory space, emitting a signal shouldn't "trigger" the other class instances? The signals are defined as class attribute. Edit: Added example how I implemented the signal.

Comment: I removed the use of signal and now getting an error that numpy is not defined?

Comment: Since you didn't `import numpy as np` I'm not surprised that it isn't defined.

Comment: Numpy is used by the Network object. Also, `from network import *` and `network` has numpy as np imported... Also tried to import numpy as np in my main script but that didn't work either. I can just the simulation fine without pathos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  First off, you are using a `ParallelPool`, which uses `ppft`... which uses `dill.source` to convert objects to source code, and then passes the source code to the new process to then build a new object and execute. You may want to try a `ProcessPool`, which uses `multiprocess`, which uses `dill`, which uses a more standard serialization of objects (like `pickle`).  Also, when you are serializing code (either with `dill` or `dill.source`) you should take care to make sure the code is as self-encapsulated as possible.  What I mean is that:

```
def sin2(x):
    import numpy as np
    return np.sin(x)**2
```

will have a better chance of serializing than

```
import numpy as np

def sin2(x):
    return np.sin(x)**2
```

because the latter relies on the serializer to trace down all the items within `sin2` that are not defined. So, simply by adding all the imports inside any function you intend to use in parallel makes it much more likely to work.  (Note that both of the above should work, but the former is easier on the serializer than the latter.) It's actually similarly true for functions and any other objects that are used inside the the namespace of the object you want to serialize, but are found by reference lookup in an the enclosing namespace.  Think about it like this: the serializer is guaranteed to ship whatever function you are targeting... and essentially transports it to the other processor and executes that code.  If there's a reference lookup that's also required, but not copied over... then it will fail.  So, help it to not fail by simplifying the namespace hierarchy enclosing the code you want to ship, and reducing the number of dependencies outside of the code you want to ship.

Comment: Ended up making the function `simulation` in the `network` module and using `ProcessingPool`. I played again with the code and it works also with `ProcessPool(node=n)`. I wonder, what's the difference between `ProcessingPool` and `ProcessPool`? Can't find `ProcessingPool` in the doc... Also, thank you for your answer, now I understand why there is `import xxx` in the function of some examples I saw (thought it was equivalent to put it at the start of the module!)

Comment: That's great.  So... `ProcessingPool = ProcessPool` for backward compatibility.  It's left there to not break people's old code.